# Change email to crypted, appended email not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change an email's `href` attribute to a crypted email dynamically via jQuery.

When I use the prop function in jQuery, the link is no more clickable. 
As you can see in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/soduno/pen/MPagWE), the last link works perfectly (where the crypt email is already hardcoded). The first link is having it's href value changed via jQuery to a crypted email, does not work (after change).

This is what I have tried:

Html:

```
<a id="test" href="mailto:mail@test.com" id="test">This does not work</a>

<a href="mailto:&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#064;&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#105;&#110;&#103;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">ThisWorks</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').prop('href', 'mailto:&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#064;&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#105;&#110;&#103;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ended up using base64 and mailto on click with window.location.href